# Sub Domain to Other Site Sub Domain

Tags: subdomain

What is the best way in a DNS record to make a subdomain point to another subdomain on another site.

E.G.: sub.domain_my_site.com --> sub.domain_other_site.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DNS way of doing that is called a 'CNAME' record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record).

Think of a DNS CNAME as an alias for something else. In your example, a web browser would show `http://sub.domain_my_site.com` in the address bar. Behind the scenes, it would continue to resolve `sub.domain_other_site.com` until it gets an IP address; and then it would connect to that IP.

CNAMEs are used all over the place. For example the well known `www.google.com` is a CNAME for `www.l.google.com.`, which presumably is a geo-distributed group of load balancers.